# How to set a session variable before anything loads in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

I want to set a session based on the URL (like http://de.domain.com or http://es.domain.com) before anything in Laravel loads and thought to do this in the `ConfigServiceProvider`:

```
public function boot() {
    // set language
    $parse = parse_url(url());
    $url_array = explode('.', $parse['host']);
    if($url_array[0] == 'domain' || $url_array[0] == 'www') {
        Session::put('current_language', Language::where('short', 'EN')->get());
        App::setLocale('en');
    } else {
        Session::put('current_language', Language::where('short', strtoupper($url_array[0]))->get());
        App::setLocale($url_array[0]);
    }
}
```

But this is not working at all. Setting it in the `Routes` sets the session,  but after pages are loaded and thus working on the next page, instead on the current one.

What's the best approach? Cause setting it in the `Routes` is surely not a good idea

Comment: the languages throughout the application are fetched using the `session('current_language')`. This can be set using a language switch button, but for stat purposes we want to put languages per subdomain. As the subdomain needs to be accessed directly, I need to set the language per session variable

Comment: If a user uses a http://es.domain address it of course should change the language of the contents to Spanish, so the session needs to be stored

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set a session variable in a service provider because in Laravel the session is initialized in this middleware:

```
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class
```

When the service providers are booted, this middleware has not been executed, because all the middleware execute after the service providers boot phase

So, the best approach would be to populate the session variable in a middleware, and let the middleware execute after Laravel `StartSession` middleware, so that the session would be accessible.

Setting the variable in a middleware should be good enough for you, as the Laravel's request cycle is:

```
Service Providers -> Middlewares -> Controllers -> Views
```

So, setting the session in a middleware will let the variable be available in your controllers and views

Comment: Thank you very much. For now I just moved it to the `handle` method in VerifyCsrfToken and it works like a charm :)

Comment: @AlvinBakker : You're welcome. I suggest you to create a custom middleware for your feature