# Laravel 9 put variable into sessionstorage before any site loads, where?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to figure out where to set a sessionStorage variable before a page loads.
I want the logic to work for any route which exists.

```
 Session::put('environment', env('APP_ENV'));
```

I was trying to do it in the `Controller` class, because every other controller extends it.

Currently I am looking at `index.php`. According to the docs thats where everything starts.

Maybe someone else has a better idea?

Comment: I guess you should place it inside the AppServiceProvider?

Comment: You should [put it in a middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34954395/how-to-set-a-session-variable-before-anything-loads-in-laravel)

Comment: I created my own middleware and it seems to work. Just session is not the sessionStorage , its the encrypted app sessions. I need to save a variable into sessionStorage or localStorage.

Comment: sessionStorage and localStorage are browser-based, not server-based, so none of this will work. `Session` variables stores the variable in the PHP server storage

Answer (score 0):

You should not store such things into session.

Best way to achieve what I wanted to do is to pass the variable to HTML in a data attribute.

I used `app.blade.php` because every site extends it.

```
<body data-environment="{{ session('environment') }}">
```

Also in my case I do not need to set an environment variable. Its already saved in the session and is called 'environment'.